# http_build_query php vs urllib.parse python для словарей

Tags: php, python, urllib, urlencode

Делаем на PHP вот такого плана структурку:

```
$enc = array(
'a' => '1',
'b' => array(
  'ba' => 'b1',
  'bb' => 'b2',
),
'c' => array(
  'ca' => 'c1',
  'cb' => 'c2',
  'cc' => 'c3',

),
```

);

И http_build_query её:

```
$example = http_build_query($enc);
```

Получаем вот такую строку:

```
a=1&b%5Bba%5D=b1&b%5Bbb%5D=b2&c%5Bca%5D=c1&c%5Bcb%5D=c2&c%5Bcc%5D=c3
```

Отправляем её куда-нибудь в питон, парсим, получаем подобные макароны:

```
urllib.parse.parse_qs("a=1&b%5Bba%5D=b1&b%5Bbb%5D=b2&c%5Bca%5D=c1&c%5Bcb%5D=c2&c%5Bcc%5D=c3")
```

Которые дают такой ответ:

```
{'a': ['1'], 'b[ba]': ['b1'], 'b[bb]': ['b2'], 'c[ca]': ['c1'], 'c[cb]': ['c2'], 'c[cc]': ['c3']}
```

Что несколько совсем не то, что было в начале. Я допускаю, что неправильно парсю, если это так - прошу совета как надо. 
А если всё же правильно парсю, тогда вопрос - это чудо, которое генерирует php, кто-то кроме php умеет обратно парсить?

Comment: А какой вы результат ожидаете?

Answer (score 0):

В application/x-www-form-urlencoded нет возможности задавать значения-массивы. Специальные символы `=` и `&` разделяют только ключи и значения и не позволяют обозначить вложенность данных. Поэтому строго говоря, кодировать такой массив некорректно. Но php идёт вам навстречу :-) Он немного расширяет application/x-www-form-urlencoded: он разворачивает массив, используя квадратные скобки для обозначения вложенности и потом кодирует плоские данные по стандарту. Питон не такой услужливый. Десериализовать ваши данные вы должны самостоятельно.

Вы можете распарсить то, что предлагает php или использовать другую сериализацию, например закодировать массив в json.

Comment: То есть, условно говоря, при преобразовании в x-www-form-urlencoded вложенной структуры, каждый язык выдаст то, во что горазд? Ну в смысле, что итог привязан к реализации процедуры?

Comment: @Gleb Да. Попробуйте закодировать в питоне. Вообще логично было бы просто приводить значения к строке (и возможно в питоне именно так и работает). Но в php массив приводится к бесполезному `Array`, поэтому там немного магии.

Comment: В защиту php хочу сказать, что такое представление удобно использовать в html-формах `<input name="foo[bar]"><input name="foo[baz]">` (хотя можно было бы обойтись и какой-нибудь точкой, но php-разработчикам скобки милее).